# Mongo Aggregation Group and Match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to group by uuid to find max version and then filter for flag? I am expecting to find the version 3 first and then see if it has got flag "Y" on it. Seems like the filter is getting applied before grouping hence I am getting version 1.

```
 {"uuid" : 1, "version" : 1, "name" : "Bob", "flag" : "Y"}
 {"uuid" : 1, "version" : 2, "name" : "Bob", "flag" : "N"}
 {"uuid" : 1, "version" : 3, "name" : "Bob", "flag" : "N"}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: are those `uuid`s actually the same value?

Answer (score 0):

[This is one way](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1SIktZeFoyB), if I get your idea:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$uuid",
    docs: {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    },
    "max_version": {
      "$max": "$version"
    }
  }
},
{
  $addFields: {
    docs: {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$docs",
        "as": "d",
        "cond": {
          $eq: [
            "$$d.version",
            "$max_version"
          ],
          $eq: [
            "$$d.flag",
            "Y"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Idea**

- $group by uuid and extract the maximum `version` on the group.
- Filter the array of documents for a `max_version` and `flag`